# Can a reference be saved to a struct of a static class in C#?

Tags: c#, struct

I have a struct in a static utility class from which another class pulls variables, usually magic numbers. It feels rather verbose to have to type something akin to `UtilityClass.SomeClassStruct.SOME_VARIABLE` everytime I wish to access a variable.

Is there a simple way to create a variable or some short-named reference to `UtilityClass.SomeClassStruct` to make my code a little easier to read and write?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define an alias with the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) directive:

```
using Foo = UtilityClass.SomeClassStruct;
```

And then use that to access your static variable:

```
Foo.SOME_VARIABLE
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I was about to suggest.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. One thing to note is that the alias seems to need to be on the left side of the assignment.